# Custom WinForm object causing VS to go non-functional

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I'm converting some C# code for a [checkbox multiselect combobox found on CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31105/A-ComboBox-with-a-CheckedListBox-as-a-Dropdown). After a bit of confusion about how to handle the RaiseEvent, I was able to get it to compile cleanly in my existing VB.net project.

When I open a form and go to the Toolbox, the CheckedComboBox appears as I would expect. However, when I attempt to drag the widget into the form, the spinner-of-death appears and that's it for VS.

I have look in the Output and other areas in VS, but I cannot see any messages or warnings appearing. Can anyone suggest a way to debug this?

Comment: Does the C# project work? If so, your *translation* is not as coherent as you think. Why did you *translate* it, though? You could add a C# Project to the Solution and reference it in you VB.NET code -- I gave a quick look at that custom Control. My personal advice is: find something else